# mysql_connect taking long time to execute

Tags: php, mysql, mysql-connect

i have following script in php to login to mysql

```
  $db_host="localhost";
  $db_user="root";
  $db_pass="123";

  $dbc=mysql_connect($db_host,$db_user,$db_pass) OR DIE (mysql_error());
  $dbs=mysql_select_db($db_name) OR DIE (mysql_error());
```

this script was working fine, now i reinstall the O.S
now i have windows 7 and iis7 and PHP Version 5.3.2 & mysql server 5.1
but now this script is not working and taking log time to execute.

Thanks

Comment: It's taking a long time AND it's not working? Is your MySQLd running? Can you connect to mysql using the console or a mysql client using those credentials?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

On Windows 7 `localhost` resolves to `::1`, and MySQL doesn't support IPv6 as far as I know.

Connecting directly to `127.0.0.1` resolves this problem; but you can edit the `hosts` file to resolve `localhost` to `127.0.0.1`, then `localhost` will work too:

1. Open C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts
2. Remove the following line, if present: `::1             localhost`
3. Add the following line, if not present: `127.0.0.1       localhost`

Answer (score 4):

Use:

```
$db_host = "127.0.0.1";
```

(or any other IP, such as `192.168.1.2`), instead of a hostname (`localhost`).

Answer (score 0):

You can also look at this link : http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/server-options.html#option_mysqld_skip-name-resolve

--skip-name-resolve option